# If a paper gets rejected two times (in two different journals) is that a bad impression if I try to submit in a different journal?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, rejection

If a paper gets rejected two times (in two different journals) is that a bad impression if I try to submit in a different journal (different from the earlier two)?

Comment: There is a reasonably high chance that at least one of the reviewers will be the same. So depending on why it was rejected the reviewer may get annoyed seeing the same paper again if you haven't addressed their concerns.

Comment: I've been in this exact situation this year. The first journal rejected my paper after a few months I sent it, stating that it didn't attend their novelty criteria, but that it should be published elsewhere. Second journal rejected it within a few weeks with no comments on it. The third paper accepted it without any suggestion or remark. It's now published on a top-quality journal (according to my country's classification). It's also in mathematics (since your name involves math). So, relax!

Comment: To support @mg4w : the *exact* same paper will likely produce the exact same result, so take the comments from the referees as guidance to improve your manuscript.

Comment: If your papers are always accepted in the first journal you submit to, then you are aiming too low.

Comment: @GEdgar - that does depend on which journal you first aim at. If Phys Rev Letters accepts it, it’s good enough.

Comment: Question does not appear to be grammatically correct. A set of historical facts is not, by definition, an impression, good or bad. Perhaps the asker means to ask a related question based on the reviewers/editors somehow knowing or being told at time of submission. Or is that part of the question also?

Answer (score 10):

**No.** In fact most of the time you do not need to (and should not) tell the editors of the new journal that your manuscript had been rejected elsewhere.

Of course, you should figure out why your manuscript was rejected and fix the issues if possible. For example if a referee says your manuscript is not acceptable because you need twice as much data to make your claims, then you should try to get twice as much data before submitting it to another journal.